# date strtotime of today is showing yesterday date not changing after 23:59:59

Tags: php, date, strtotime

i want to echo today's date in option but date of strtotime of today is not changing after 23:59:59 instead it changes after 5:30 am in morning . right now todays date is 01-10-2019 but its still showing me 30-09-2019.. how to echo strtotime of today which changes after 23:59:59,  any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("today")); ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to account for the server's timezone settings

Comment: how to do server timezone setting.. i am using latest wamp server

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: still unable to figure out. can you give me working solution my time zone is -(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search I found this as answer..

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("today"));
?>
```